# No suitable driver found when using Migratus with SQLite in a Clojure project

Tags: sqlite, clojure

I'm new to Clojure and I've been struggling to get Migratus to work with an SQLite database. I've been through a bit of a debugging and I feel stuck! :(

The issue is that, when I try running migrations, I get the following error:

```bash
Execution error (SQLException) at java.sql.DriverManager/getConnection (DriverManager.java:702).
No suitable driver found for jdbc:://127.0.0.1/
```

(which is weird: this should be referring to a SQLite file, not the local host)

Using `java.sql.DriverManager`, I can successfully establish a connection to the SQLite database manually. So the driver seems to be set up correctly.

This is my `project.clj`:

```clj
(defproject sample-project "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "TODO"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
                 [io.pedestal/pedestal.route "0.6.0"]
                 [io.pedestal/pedestal.service "0.6.0"]
                 [io.pedestal/pedestal.jetty "0.6.0"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.7.12"]
                 [org.xerial/sqlite-jdbc "3.42.0.0"]
                 [migratus/migratus "1.5.1"]
                 [buddy/buddy-hashers "2.0.167"]]
  :source-paths ["src"]
  :repl-options {:init-ns sample-project.core}
  :profiles {:dev {:aliases {"run-dev" ["trampoline" "run" "-m" "simple-api-proxy.werver/run-dev"]}
                   :dependencies [[io.pedestal/pedestal.service-tools "0.6.0"]]}}
  :main sample-project.core)
```

And this is how the `run-migrations` function is configured in `core.clj`:

```clj
(ns simple-api-proxy.db
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as jdbc]
           [migratus.core :as migratus]))

(def db-spec 
 {:classname "org.sqlite.JDBC"
    :subprotocol "sqlite"
    :subname ":db.sqlite3"}) ; Also tried with 'db.sqlite3' and "jdbc:sqlite:db.sqlite3"

#_{:clj-kondo/ignore [:clojure-lsp/unused-public-var]}
(defn run-migrations "Run migrations" []
  (let [config {:store :database
                :migration-dir "resources/migrations"
                :db db-spec}]
    (migratus/migrate config)))
```

Am I missing something? Is there any incompatibility between Migratus and SQLite?

Comment: You said that you can successfully establish a connection manually - how do you do that exactly?

Comment: On REPL, I ran `(import 'java.sql.DriverManager)` and then `(let [conn (DriverManager/getConnection "jdbc:sqlite:db.sqlite3")](.close conn))`. It ran without errors, so I assumed the connection was established.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

afaik the `migratus` db spec declaration uses different prop names:

the [documentation](https://github.com/yogthos/migratus#example-configurations) shows something like

```
:migratus {:store :database
           :migration-dir "migrations"
           :db {:dbtype "sqlite"
                :dbname "db.sqlite3"}}
```

so, probably you need to update your migration spec.